# Postgresql gin index high cpu usage ratio

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I design a table with jsonb column to store userlist, and I set up a gin index on that column.

```
select * from table where userlist @> '"Username":"a01"'::josnb
```

My data type in table like

```
`[{"Username":"a01"},{"Username":"a02"},{"Username":"a03"}....`]
```

When I had backend unit test, the query speed was fast.

But when I wrote a function to call this sp, I found it had very high cpu usage ratio problems(almost 100%).

After I vacuum table and reindex this DB, it down to 80%, but it's still high.

I don't know how to decrease the problem. 
if u have any idea, I am looking forward your suggestions, thank you.

```
DECLARE @EndCNT;
SET @EndCNT = 10000;

WHILE @EndCNT > 0
BEGIN

SELECT public.query_cust('a01');
SET @EndCNT = @EndCNT - 1;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found it's jsonb data type problem.

If you store too long jsonb data, 
when system load data into memory, it makes unavoidable high CPU ratio usage.